# How to convert two 1d array to one 2d array to apply Object.fromEntries in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I had two array:

```js
const keys = [a, b, c]
const values = [[], [], []]
```

I want to convert it to a 2d array:

```js
const entries = [[a, []], [b, []], [c, []]]
```

How can I do it?

P.S. Actually I want to apply `Object.fromEntries` to initialise an object in the end.

```js
const x = {a: [], b: [], c: []}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to skin this cat

***Array.map*** plus ***fromEntries*** are two operations and is likely the slowest for large datasets - the other two are likely equally performant. If you only have a very small dataset, then there will not be any measurable difference.

```js
const keys = ["a", "b", "c"];
const values = [[], [], []];

const entries = keys.map((key, i) => [key, values[i]]);
const obj = Object.fromEntries(entries);

console.log(obj)
```

***forEach*** needs an assign before

```js
const keys = ["a", "b", "c"];
const values = [[], [], []];

const obj = {};
keys.forEach((key,i) => obj[key] = values[i]);

console.log(obj);
```

***reduce*** also needs an assignment but that is part of the execution, saving a line of code.

```js
const keys = ["a", "b", "c"];
const values = [[], [], []];


const obj = keys.reduce((acc,cur,i) => (acc[cur] = values[i], acc),{})

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thank you, may I ask what is the difference between each method, in terms of performance or other things, which one is suggested in my case?

Comment: For a small dataset, the differences would be virtually none. For larger datasets, forEach and reduce would likely be more memory-efficient than a map + Object.fromEntries

Answer (score 1):

const data = keys.map((key, index) => [key, values[index]]);

you can use this data like this : Object.fromEntries(data)

Comment: This was already suggested 20 minutes ago

Answer (score 1):

You may consider [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), to make `Object.fromEntries` obsolete:

```js
const [a, b, c] = [`keyA`, `keyB`, `keyC`];
const values = [[], [], []];
const combined = [a, b, c].reduce((acc, val, i) => 
  ({...acc, [val]: values[i]}), {});
console.log(combined);
```